# Automatically merge split ms access database

Tags: ms-access

At work we have a split ms access database. The backend lies on a drive that is mapped locally (so for everyone it's the same path). I know want to create a button in the frontend that when clicked automatically creates a merged version of the database. This version is necessary for out specific backup/history needs. I have very little knowledge of VBA programming, so any help is appreciated.

To create the merged version the code should just execute the following:
Create duplicate frontend (?)
Delete all existing tables in the duplicate
Import tables from the backend into the duplicate

(I am aware that it is not such a good idea to merge split databases, but in this case with many users that have absolutely no knowledge of CS it is the most usable solution)

Comment: Could you elaborate on what it is you hope to achieve? I am not clear on your desired outcome. Typically in a split application scenario the back-end database contains the data for the application, the front-end contains the forms, reports and logic, and perhaps some cached (static) lookup data with a link to the back-end tables. I am not clear on what copying the front-end database will do for you. Do you need to create a backup of the actual data for the application periodically?

Comment: I have to make a backup that contains the data plus all queries and forms. Does that answer the question or is is unclear? 
What I currently do by hand is copy the front end, delete all tables and then I import the tables from the backend and store this merges database.

Comment: Sort of. Do the queries and forms in the front-end change often, or are you simply looking to create a self-contained (working) application that has a backup of the data along with the front-end application code?

Comment: The queries and forms in the frontend do change occasionally. Therefore to reproduce a certain report for a specific situation in the past for example it may be important to have this "self-contained snapshot of history".

Comment: Another use case for this technique is when I wanted to combine the front-end and back-end to share a demo database in a forum.  It was easier to have the files  combined than to have users get stuck when the the linked tables were pointing to the wrong path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Module in the front-end database with the following Function

```
Public Function ImportLinkedTables()
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, tbd As DAO.TableDef
Dim tablesToLink As Collection, item As Variant, a() As String
Const LinkPrefix = ";DATABASE="
Set cdb = CurrentDb

Set tablesToLink = New Collection
For Each tbd In cdb.TableDefs
    If tbd.Connect Like (LinkPrefix & "*") Then
        '' tab-delimited list: TableDef name [tab] Source file [tab] Source table
        tablesToLink.Add tbd.Name & vbTab & Mid(tbd.Connect, Len(LinkPrefix) + 1) & vbTab & tbd.SourceTableName
    End If
Next
Set tbd = Nothing

For Each item In tablesToLink
    a = Split(item, vbTab, -1, vbBinaryCompare)
    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, a(0)
    Debug.Print "Importing [" & a(0) & "]"
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", a(1), acTable, a(2), a(0), False
Next
Set tablesToLink = Nothing

Set cdb = Nothing
DoCmd.Quit
End Function
```

Create a Macro named "ImportLinkedTables" with a single step:

```
RunCode
    Function Name  ImportLinkedTables()
```

The code behind the form button to kick off the process would be

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim wshShell As wshShell
Dim accdbName As String, command As String

Const SourceFolder = "Y:\_dev\"
Const DestFolder = "C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\"

accdbName = Application.CurrentProject.Name

'' copy front-end file to new location
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
fso.CopyFile SourceFolder & accdbName, DestFolder & accdbName, True
Set fso = Nothing

Set wshShell = New wshShell
command = """"
command = command & wshShell.RegRead("HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\" & Application.Version & "\Common\InstallRoot\Path")
command = command & "MSACCESS.EXE"" """ & DestFolder & accdbName & """ /x ImportLinkedTables"
wshShell.Run command, 7, False
Set wshShell = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much for the provided code! It looks like this will work! I will try this sometime in the next week (something more urgent has come up).

Comment: This was great starter code for me.  My back-end had was password protected so I had to add some code to `ImportLinkedTables` to open the back-end with a password parameter before running `.TransferDatabase`.  I found a technique for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55374442/1898524).