# MS Access DoCmd.Transferdatabase when source has a password

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to import tables from various databases on a monthly basis. Once the tables are imported, the databases are archived and not looked at again.

I have the following VBA code which works fine when a DB is not password protected:

```
Private Sub ImportTheData(ByVal dbImport As String)

DoCmd.SetWarnings False 'Turn OFF display alerts

'Import the full activity & comments table from the Import DB to a temporary table
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", dbImport, acTable, "tbl_Activity", "tbl_TempActivity", True
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", dbImport, acTable, "tbl_Comments", "tbl_TempComments", True

'code continues ...
```

The last parameter (storelogin) is set to true, but there seems to be no way to programmatically set those login parameters (password).

When I run the code, the user is prompted to enter the password (despite the SetWarnings = False). As I'm importing dozens of files each time this is not a viable solution.

**Is there a way to programatically import tables using `DoCmd.TransferDatabase` when a file is password protected and if so how?**

Comment: Reading this https://forums.windowssecrets.com/showthread.php/105224-TransferDatabase-Password-(Access-2007) you may need to open the database and that property doesn't apply to Access DB's.  Maybe the link option in here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transferdatabase or look at SQL `Select Into` specifying a connection string in the from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the database with DAO, supplying the password, then you can import the tables.

```
Public Sub ImportEncr()

    Const dbImport = "D:\DbEncr.accdb"
    Const sPassword = "foobar"

    Dim DB As DAO.Database
    Set DB = DBEngine.OpenDatabase(Name:=dbImport, Options:=False, ReadOnly:=False, Connect:=";PWD=" & sPassword)

    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", dbImport, acTable, "tblEncr", "tblEncr", False

    DB.Close
    Set DB = Nothing

End Sub
```

`StoreLogin` applies to linking tables from ODBC databases.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL and build a SQL statement and `.RunSQL` that I believe.

An example SQL would be

`SELECT * into tblIMPORT
FROM xyz IN '' '; database=C:\Workspace\Database1.accdb;PWD=test';`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. +1 I ended up using Andre's but will test your solution.