# TransferDatabase keep asking for a password though it has already been supplied at opendatabase method

Tags: vba, ms-access

The code is below, the transferdatabase method keep asking password even already supplied in the opendatabase method. I am using Access 2016.

```
tmp = "C:\DATA_BE.accdb"

Set db = OpenDatabase(tmp, false, False, "MS Access;PWD=Password")

DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", tmp, acTable, "tblName", "tblName", False, False

db.Close
```

Comment: Try as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55374442/3820271), especially using `";PWD=Password"` as connect string.

Comment: Thank you @Andre, I copied what has been written in that threads and just change a little bit to match my variables, yet still it is asking a password. I intend to link multiple tables externally.